# Is it possible to bind an array to dropdown using ngoptions rather than ngrepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am not able to bind an array to my dropdown list using ngOptions. Neither I am able to understand AngularJS documentation for the same.

```
<html ng-app="">

    <body>
        <div class="container" ng-init="numberText=['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Four Plus']">
            <select ng-options="label for schedule in numberText"></select>{{numberText}}</div>
        <select>
            <option ng-repeat="n in numberText">{{n}}</option>
        </select>
    </body>

</html>
```

I don't understand what documentation is trying to say about

```
label for value in array
select as label for value in array
label group by group for value in array
label disable when disable for value in array
label group by group for value in array track by trackexpr
label disable when disable for value in array track by trackexpr
label for value in array | orderBy:orderexpr track by trackexpr (for including a filter with track by)
```

I am seeking for explanation what all of this means.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hw9bexs9/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add ng-model and change label to arr element like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hw9bexs9/2/)

```
<select ng-model="test" ng-options="schedule for schedule in numberText"></select>
```

Comment: can you please explain how this is working? Also why it's not working without ng-model

Comment: First ng-options requires ng-model, and not working without it (more about required tou can read [here](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html)).
"in" mean the same as [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) js sintax.
"for" in this case mean label and value of option element